# Executing LINQ Queries In Excel To SQL

Tags: linq, excel, vba, sqlmetal

I want to be able to interact with an SQL database using LINQ and Excel (it's a legacy thing).  Is this sort of thing possible?

I'm screwing around with SQLMetal, and have generated some database classes in VB, but they don't seem to go in smoothly into Excel (I'm getting a lot of red error text).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know much about LINQ but is there a reason why you can’t either use ADO or the import external data feature in excel(Data-Import external data-New database query)?